# Get WordPress post's top category name instead of slug

Tags: php, wordpress

I've found numerous posts regarding people pulling the slug or the ID of a WordPress post's top category, but I need to pull the name specifically.

Here's the current structure:

```
Spring 2016 (slug 2016-spring)
    Feature (feature)
    Giving Highlights (giving-highlights)
    etc.
```

The code I have works perfectly in pulling the top level slug/nicename (2016-spring), but I need it to return the name/cat_name (Spring 2016) instead.

The code I'm using is:

```
$category = get_the_category();
$cat_tree = get_category_parents($category[0]->term_id, FALSE, ':', TRUE);
$top_cat = split(':',$cat_tree);
$parent = $top_cat[0];
echo $parent;
```

What do I need to change in order to be pulling the name?

Comment: The category has a parent term: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category

Comment: I get that, but I guess I'm not sure how to use that in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution I use in my current environment:

```
$categories = get_the_category();
if ( ! empty($categories)) {
    if (sizeOf($categories) > 1) {
        $output = $categories[1]->name;
    } elseif (sizeOf($categories) == 1) {
        $output = $categories[0]->name;
    } else {
        $output = 'Please Assign A Category';
    }
}
```

We have situations where some posts only use the top level category, while others use a deeper category within that for sorting purposes. Your situation will obviously vary; if all your posts will be at least 1 deep within the tree, you can just use the `$output=$categories[1]->name;` line and that will be fine. Ours is a bit more robust just in case.

Comment: Ah thank you!!! This is exactly what I needed. Probably a bit bulky, but yeah, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try to simply pull the category name of the parent using `get_category()` ?

Try this

```
$parent = $top_cat[0];
$pcat = get_category( $parent ) ;

// Then 
echo $pcat->cat_name ; 
// OR
echo $pcat->category_nicename ;
```

Comment: Added it in, but it doesn't display anything for me when I run it.